# CoreServicesUIAgent stealing/ taking Window-focus

Tags: applications, apple-silicon, focus

Since updating my MBP with M1-Chip to Ventura 13.3.1 the apps I currently work with are not in focus anymore after a random time.

I found out with a python-script which prints out the name of the application currently in focus that it was `CoreServicesUIAgent` which stole the window-focus.
I already restarted the Mac multiple times and I don't know what else I can do.
Here are some links where users have a similar problems

- https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/active-window-loses-focus.2321723/
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253842456