# Why does Safari steal focus and come to the foreground when next.js dev server shows an error?

Tags: macos, safari, window-manager, ventura

I just started developing my first web application using next.js and VisualStudioCode. VisualStudioCode saves any edits by default after a very short pause of inactivity, so whenever I type slowly, it saves incomplete code. next.js includes a development server that detects changed files and compiles them immediately. It then reloads the web application and displays any compilation errors. Since the code is saved without my intervention, compilation errors occur almost immediately after I start typing.

The problem is that whenever an error is detected, Safari steals the focus from VisualStudioCode and brings it to the front. This makes the automatic update feature completely useless.

How can I prevent Safari from EVER doing this?

I am running macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a) on an Intel MacBookPro with no external hardware connected, all third-party window managers terminated, and no Safari plugins installed.

Other people report similar problems with no real solution:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253033475
- [CoreServicesUIAgent stealing/ taking Window-focus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459114/coreservicesuiagent-stealing-taking-window-focus)